# Why does double vision when drinking happen?

Tags: vision, alcohol

Why do you see double sometimes when you're drunk?  Its weird because it seems to happen more when you try to focus.

- Try to look at something when you're drinking and it barely seems to double up
- Try to focus on it more than just immediately, and slowly the image seems to separate
- Refocusing on new object seems to re-focus and lets you not see double

Why does this happen?

Edit:
http://www.esquire.com/news-politics/q-and-a/a5711/double-vision-causes-0509/ This seems to imply an inability to focus, however, if I try to refocus on a new object it works out

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with alcohol. Its related with eyes and refocusing from far to near object (and vice-versa). You should change the tags.

Comment: I have experienced same thing while practicing mindfulness. When I just look at a flame I could see it as I normally do but trying to focus on it more will cause the flame to double up and yet refocusing will bring normal vision. As @another'Homosapien' said I think it has something to do with vision.